# Is there a way to find the R code from a shinyapp.io link?

Tags: r, shiny

I recently saw a really well developed shinyapp and was wanting to know the code behind certain aspects of the app. Was wondering if there was a way to find out the code, or would I have to directly contact the author?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to contact the author. No other option. At max you can look CSS and JS files from source of the page.